# Why is « prendre ACTE de » synonymous of « prendre NOTE de »?

Tags: sens

« Prendre note de » means "take note of", and these meanings are obvious. Students, journalists, investigators manually [take notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note-taking) of what they notice, and to help them remember what they notice!

> prendre note de
> verb
>
> [take note of to notice and remember](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/french-english/prendre-note-de)

**But why on earth does « prendre ACTE de » almost mean the same as « prendre NOTE de »?** In South African English, "take act of" isn't grammatical!  But "take note of" is! And what does it even to mean to "take act of"???

> [**Prendre acte**, faire constater en justice ; déclarer qu'on prend note de quelque chose pour s'en prévaloir éventuellement.](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/acte/879#167471)

> **Définition**
>
> [Constater un fait, spécialement une déclaration d'une partie au cours d'un procès.](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17489350)

[image]

[image]

Comment: A good example that one shouldn't translate idiomatic expressions literally or word-by-word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Acte*** has not one of its usual meanings here but its legalese one which is also found in the expression ***[dont acte](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dont_acte)***.

English "**act**" shares the same one, #7 in the [MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/act):

> "a formal record of something done or transacted".

***Prendre acte*** is stronger than ***prendre note***. It suggests (usually as a metaphor) that some legal action might follow.

Compare:

> ***J'en prends note***: I take note of it.

and

> ***J'en prends acte***: Point taken. Literally: "I take a transcript of it".
> ***Dont acte***: Same meaning.